# Can forcedType accept fully qualified names to a column?

Tags: java, jooq

I started to use `<forcedType>` a while ago to be able to use `enum` for known-types. For example I have

```xml
<forcedType>
    <name>AdminToolFeatureTypeConverter</name>
    <expression>admin_tool_feature_type_id</expression>
</forcedType>
```

which will map any `admin_tool_featury_type_id` columns to the `AdminToolFeatureType` `enum`:

```
public enum AdminToolFeatureType {

    BASIC, BASIC_PLUS;

    public Long getValue() {
        return this.ordinal() + 1L;
    }       
}
```

Now the thing is that I always call that column `admin_tool_featury_type_id` if it's a `FOREIGN KEY` but in the **table** `admin_tool_feature_type` this column is simply called `id`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE admin_tool_feature_type (

    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    -- and so on ...    
);
```

This is what becomes a problem as I `JOIN` on `admin_tool_add_on_type`:

```
Map<AdminToolAddOnType, AdminToolAddOnDTO> fetchMap = this.ctx.select(
        ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.ID,
        // ..
        adminToolAddOnIdToken.field(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE.ADD_ON_ID_TOKEN)
        )
    .from(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON)
    // ..
    .join(adminToolAddOnIdToken)
        .on(adminToolAddOnIdToken.field(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE.ADMIN_TOOL_FEATURE_TYPE_ID).eq(adminToolFeatureType)
                // ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE.ID is type Long
                // ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE_ID is type AdminToolAddOnType
                .and(adminToolAddOnIdToken.field(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE.ID).eq(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE_ID)))
```

The problem is that `ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE.ID` is type `Long` but `ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE_ID` is type `AdminToolAddOnType`.

Now the question is what'd the simplest way to fix this issue. I do not want to rename `admin_tool_feature_type.id` into `admin_tool_feature_type.admin_tool_feature_type_id` because this would interfere with the coding standard.

Is there an easy way to extend `<forcedType>` such that `admin_tool_feature_type.id` will be generated as type `AdminToolAddOnType` instead of `Long`?

What I meant with the title was if it's possible to do something like:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <name>AdminToolFeatureTypeConverter</name>
    <expression>admin_tool_feature_type_id</expression>
    <!-- Could be a list of fully qualified names to columns -->
    <fullyQualified>
        admin_tool_feature_type.id
    </fullyQualified>
</forcedType>
```

I already tried e.g.

```xml
<forcedType>
    <name>AdminToolFeatureTypeConverter</name>
    <expression>
        <!-- also : my_database.admin_tool_feature_type.id, -->
        admin_tool_feature_type.id,
        admin_tool_feature_type_id
    </expression>
</forcedType>
```

but this does not seem to be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that this is actually possible if you read what the documentation says:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <name>AdminToolFeatureTypeConverter</name>
    <expression>
        my_database.admin_tool_feature_type.id|admin_tool_feature_type_id
    </expression>
</forcedType>
```

One has to use `|` instead of `,` to separate the expressions. I don't know why I thought it's comma separated.

Comment: *"I don't know why I thought it's comma separated."* - It used to be that way in very early versions of jOOQ... Until someone had a comma in their table names ;)

Comment: @LukasEder :D You can have a comma in table names? O_o That's weird, but maybe I really saw that from an older version of jOOQ which got me confused here :)

Comment: *"You can have a comma in table names? O_o"* - Don't ask

Comment: @LukasEder :D Got it ^^